# MSYS shell keeping script file open, preventing modifications

Tags: windows, shell, sh, file-descriptor, msys

Usually when running a shell script, the shell keeps the script file open throughout the execution. On Unix systems this is not a problem.

However, Windows prevents modifications to a file that is opened in that way. Which means that if a script is running in MSYS, I need to kill the shell before I can modify the script. This is annoying because `git pull` or `svn up` will fail.

I am looking for a solution to that problem, for instance through specific options I could put in the `#!/bin/sh` line, or some kind of shell one-liner that would maybe cause the script to copy itself in a safe place and execute the copy instead.

Comment: isn't windows wonderful? I've run into similar problems. I've never seen a `#!/bin/sh ...` option as you describe. What about running the whole thing in a Linux VM? Also, you're aware of Cygwin? It is more windowish, maybe it has an option (but I doubt it). Post the Cygwin user group? There is also an MSYS usergroup on http://old(2?).nabble.com (can't remember if its old or old2. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the hints. I’d love to run the script on Linux instead, but it’s a build script that uses the Visual Studio compilers, so Windows is a requirement. It’s running in a VM hosted on Linux, though!

Answer (score 3):

You could let the script re-exec itself. Split it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -z "$MYSCRIPT_REEXEC"; then
    : stuff you do before git pull
    exec env MYSCRIPT_REEXEC=1 sh -c "git pull; . '$0'"
fi
: stuff you do after git pull
```

This is a simple case, `$0` may not contain apostrophs, and the arguments and any variables set in the first half are inaccessible. It’s hard to give a better generic example – maybe, if I could see the original script?

If this *still* does not work, try this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -z "$MYSCRIPT_REEXEC"; then
    : stuff you do before git pull
    env MYSCRIPT_REEXEC=1 sh -c "sleep 1; git pull; . '$0'" &
    exit 0
fi
: stuff you do after git pull
```

In this case, though, return codes will *also* be all wrong, as will anything waiting for the script.